# asp.net-mvc ajax json post to controller action method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I know that same questions have answers, but they don't work in my project.
I have controller were i send message to employee.
id i take  with ajax.
email i take from db. but getEmployeeEmail() returns me my email( it's right)
Controller name: EmployersActivity

Code don't work when i send post.
My ajax post code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".buttonSendEmail").click(function () {
            var orderText = $(".orderData").text();
            alert(orderText);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: "@(Url.Action("Create", "EmployersActivity"))",
                data: { id: 1 },
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                error: function (message) {
                    alert("error on start")
                    $(".contentReqGood").show();
                    redirect();
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.status === 1) {
                        alert("error")
                    } else {
                        $(".contentReqGood").show();
                        redirect();}})})});
```

asp.net mvc code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        var email = db.employees.Find(id);
        if (email == null)
            return HttpNotFound();
        if (email != null)
        {


            if (db.SaveChanges() == 1)
            {
                string mailTemplate;
                string title = "asdasd";
                string preview = "asdasdasd";
                var sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Templates/" + "InfoEmail.txt"));

                mailTemplate = sr.ReadToEnd();

                string messageBody = string.Format(mailTemplate, title, preview);

                new MailSender
                {
                    Sender = "news@omegasoftware.eu",
                    Recipient = "news@omegasoftware.eu",
                    RecipientsBcc = getEmployeeEmail(),
                    Subject = title,
                    Body = messageBody
                }.Send();}}
        return View();}
```

Comment: Remove the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` option (either that or you need to stringify the data - `data: JSON.stringify({ id: 1 }),`). And you can remove the pointless `traditional: true,` option (you are not sending a simple array). Then you need to delete the `dataType: "json",` (you are not returning json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues regarding current example:

1) `[Authorize]` attribute is unnecessary on POST method because using it in GET action method should be enough to prevent unauthorized users.

2) Since you're sending AJAX request to a POST method which includes `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute, it is necessary to send the CSRF prevention token into AJAX request.

3) Remove `dataType: "json"`, `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` and `traditional: true` since you're sending single integer data and not using an array or JSON-formatted string.

4) AJAX callbacks are intended to stay in same page, hence `return View()` should be replaced with `return PartialView()`.

Based from 4 issues above, if it's necessary to use AJAX, you should set the request and controller action like following example below:

**AJAX Request**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".buttonSendEmail").click(function () {
        var orderText = $(".orderData").text();
        alert(orderText);

        var form = $('form');
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Create", "EmployersActivity")",
            data: { id: 1, __RequestVerificationToken: token },
            error: function (message) {
                alert("error on start");
                // other stuff
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $(".contentReqGood").show();
                // other stuff
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var email = db.employees.Find(id);
    if (email == null)
        return HttpNotFound();
    if (email != null)
    {
        // do something
    }
    return PartialView("_PartialViewName");
}
```

Other than that, if you want to pass entire viewmodel content to POST action method or use redirection with `RedirectToAction()` after submit, then you should use normal form submit (with `Html.BeginForm()` helper) instead.